# ExtJs 3 or 4 - LostFocus event

Tags: javascript, extjs

In ExtJs there is an "focus" event listener for `Ext.form.Text` (alias - textfield), it forks just fine. But i actually nead to catch "lost focus" event for textfield.

**Is there a event listner in ExtJs or JavaScript, that will help me to handle "lost focus" event?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The event you're looking for is [blur](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.TextField).

Comment: tnx a lot.. BTW: do you know why it's called 'blur'? o_O

Comment: Don't know the real origins of the name, but in Javascript the "form input loses focus" event is also called blur, so it makes sense to use the same in ExtJS.

Comment: Also, if I answered your question successfully, you might as well mark my answer as correct... thanks :)

Comment: well, i just have a veird bug.. focus and blur fires at the same time o_O.. but this mb becose i using ExtJs4 beta1

Answer (score 2):

focus and blur are not fired at the same time.... don't forget that when you give focus to a radio, you also loose focus(blur) by another radio, then the two events fired are a focus event for the radio you are selecting a blur event for the radio you are deselecting. that's the trick!!